What should I use to caulk the seams of resin shower panels?
I am removing a 1 piece combo of a tub and shower surround bolted to studs originally in a manufactured home.  Back wall is outside wall.
I plan on creating my own panels with epoxy on a Menards plas-tex polywall white matte bathroom panel glued onto either a 4x8 Styrofoam panel.  Possibly fiberglass roll between for strength & additional waterproofing.  Or on a 4x8 plywood board versus the Styrofoam.
Then for the basin, I was goin to try and do the same over a basin pan from Vevor, waterproof shower substrate (model# JQ-3860P.  It comes with ONLY the connecting strip to connect the 2 panels.
What should I use to seam/waterproof cornets and all other panels?  Is there something that is transparent and waterproof?

Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your title to make it a single, clear, specific question (if my revision wasn't appropriate). There are many transparent bathroom-oriented caulks on the store shelf, so your question is unclear (so to speak).
